# Executing a @PreUpdate JPA listener synchronously

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring Boot app I have an Event domain class, to which I've added the following entity listener

```
public class Event {
    // other class members omitted

    private Status status;

    @PreUpdate
    private void beforeUpdate() {
        status = Status.COMPLETE
    }
}
```

I update event instances via the following service method call

```
var updatedEvent = eventService.updateEvent(event);
logger.debug("Updated event status: " + updatedEvent.getStatus());
```

The implementation of this method just calls a repository

```
public Event updateEvent(Event event) {
    return eventRepository.save(event);
}
```

If the event's initial status is ACTIVE, then the log statement prints

> Updated event status: ACTIVE

because the `@PreUpdate` method is called (asynchronously?) after `updateEvent` returns.
The result is that the `updatedEvent` object does not include the changes made by `@PreUpdate`.

I could workaround this my re-fetching the object from the database, but is there another way to get the updated object, including the changes made by the `@PreUpdate`?

I had a look at the [JPA docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform_common_criteria_certification/5/html/hibernate_entity_manager_reference_guide/listeners), but they don't specify whether `@PreUpdate` is synchronous or asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The listener is invoked as part of the "flushing" of the entity. If you don't flush explicitly, flushing is done automatically right before transaction commit. So if you want this to happen "synchronously", you will have to run `eventRepository.flush()` in `updateEvent`